# Copy file in case it does not exist or is older

Tags: bash, shell

I have two different directories A and B. Now I want to copy all files from directory A to directory B, but only in case they do not exist in directory B *or* if they exists but are *older* than the files in directory A.

Comment: Do you know about rsync?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
cp -R -u -p /source /destination
```

Comment: Thanks Juanpe! Can I add the option to only copy files with the same data type, e.g. *.txt ? Or does -R simply take ALL files no matter what?

Comment: @QueryJoe It takes all files no matter what, but you can tell the copy command which files you´d want to copy, update your question to include your new requirements and I'll update my answer to fit. Also have a look at Micha's suggestion.